# Redux Observable: How to use action.payload in latter part of chain?

Tags: redux, redux-observable

I've ran into this issue quite a few times where I want to access `action.payload` further down the chain. But by then, the argument passed to `mergeMap` has already changed to something else.

Given my action looks like this:

```
{
  type: BUY_GEMS,
  payload: { value: 123, productIdentifier: "ABC123" }
}
```

And this epic:

```
function purchaseGems(action$, store) {
  return action$
    .ofType(BUY_GEMS)
    .mergeMap(action => {
      const { productIdentifier } = action.payload; // <-------- works because it's the first mergeMap in this sequence
      return Observable.fromPromise(
        // Some promise call
      ).catch(error => Observable.of(buyGemsRejected(error)));
    })
    .mergeMap(action => {
      const { value } = action.payload; // <----------- doesn't work because "action" is now just the response of the Promise above.
      ...
    });
}
```

How would I do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This trick is to just place your second `mergeMap` inside the closure where the action is available. In fact, even if you didn't need access to it I generally recommend this pattern in redux-observable whereby you isolate your Observable chains inside your single top-level merging strategy operator (`mergeMap`, `switchMap`, etc) because it makes future refactoring like this easier as well as easier error isolation (if added).

```
function purchaseGems(action$, store) {
  return action$
    .ofType(BUY_GEMS)
    .mergeMap(action => {
      const { productIdentifier } = action.payload;
      return Observable.fromPromise(somePromise)
        .catch(error => Observable.of(buyGemsRejected(error)))
        .mergeMap(response => {
          const { value } = action.payload;
          // ...
        });
    });
}
```

---

Your example contained `Observable.fromPromise()` which I assume is just pseudo code, so I followed suit with `Observable.fromPromise(somePromise)` for more clarity for other readers.

Comment: what is the real thing for Observable.fromPromice, and not the pseudo code?

Comment: @LazarNikolic You can do `import {from} from 'rxjs';` and use `from(somePromise)`